# Put list of modified files in git commit message

Tags: bash, git, shell, unix, version-control

I am trying to add an alias to my `.gitconfig` that will automatically add all modified files in the current repo to the commit message.

I've tried to work with the output of `git status --porcelain` using `cut` and `awk`.

I got `awk` to work but I am sure there is a better solution that will yield a nicer commit message.

```
# in my .gitconfig
g = !git commit --all --message "edited:$(git status --porcelain | awk '{printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\",\":\"\"),$2} END{print \"\"}')"
# on the command-line
git commit --all --message "edited:$(git status --porcelain | awk '{printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\",\":\"\"),$2} END{print \"\"}')"
```

From `git log`, I see commit messages like `edited:dir1/file1,dir2/file2`.

I would like to clean up the code and/or improve the commit message.

Comment: I think `git diff --cached --name-status` would yield a more accurate status of committed files.

Comment: Git knows the files are changed and what lines. The message should explain why. 
When you don't want to tell it every commit, consider making a `.git_reason` file and use that as a default message. Each time you change project / story / task, you can overwrite the default reason.

Comment: If you want to see what changed in a commit, use `git show` or `git show --stat` on that commit (see also `git log --raw`). If you want to see *why* the *human who made that change*, made that change, read the log message—but for this to work, the human who makes the change must actually describe, to the human reading the log message in the future, *why* he or she made that change.

Comment: Sometimes git is used to control assets other than source code which are produced by people who cannot be realistically expected to write the message (artists). Producing a message a list of the changed files is quite good improvement over  using a fixed message like "Artwork changed". The message is then useful in a log file viewed on GitHub or in some log viewer (IDE, Tortoise).

Comment: If you just care about the files that were changed (and not their status), similar to ElpieKay's answer, use `git diff --name-only`

Answer (score 4):

That information is already available in your commit. You just have to run `git log --stat` to see it.

I use this so often that I defined an alias for it in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    ls = log --stat
```

So whenever I use `git ls` I get the stat output.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that does exactly what I want, but it is pretty ghastly.

Here is what it looks like in my `.gitconfig`:

```
g = "!f() { git commit -am \"$(echo $@)\" && git push; }; f" "$([ -z \"$(git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?A\\s')\" ] || git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?A\\s' | awk 'BEGIN{print \"Added:\"} {printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\", \":\"\"), $2} END{print \"\"}')" "$([ -z \"$(git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?C\\s')\" ] || git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?C\\s' | awk 'BEGIN{print \"Copied:\"} {printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\", \":\"\"), $2} END{print \"\"}')" "$([ -z \"$(git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?D\\s')\" ] || git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?D\\s' | awk 'BEGIN{print \"Deleted:\"} {printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\", \":\"\"), $2} END{print \"\"}')" "$([ -z \"$(git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?M\\s')\" ] || git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?M\\s' | awk 'BEGIN{print \"Modified:\"} {printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\", \":\"\"), $2} END{print \"\"}')" "$([ -z \"$(git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?R\\s')\" ] || git status --porcelain | grep '^\\s\\?R\\s' | awk 'BEGIN{print \"Renamed:\"} {printf \"%s%s\",(NR>1?\", \":\"\"), $2} END{print \"\"}')";
```

Sorry if my question was not clear.

The idea is that I can just type `git g` to

1. add changes in tracked files,
2. commit (with a half-decent message), and
3. push.

Example commit message:

`Added: file1, file2 Deleted: trash, rubbish Modified: work_in_progress`

Answer (score 0):

If using the command line interface for `git commit` (default behaviour) you just need to uncomment the relevant lines that are already generated by Git. Search for the line with `Changes to be commited` and under that line there should be lines indicating the files modified/added/removed/moved.

Comment: is there a way to do that automatically using a hook?

Comment: That goes beyond my knowledge